# Counting the topologies of a fixed number of open sets

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $\ X\ $ be a finite set, and $\ n:= |X| > 0.\ $ Let $\ Top(X)\ $ be the set of all topologies in $\ X,\ $ and $\ top(n) := \left|Top(X)\right|.\ $ Define:

$$ Top(X;t)\ :=\ \left\{T\in Top\left(X\right)\ :\ |T| = t \right\} $$
and
$$ top(n;t)\ :=\ \left|Top\left(X;t\right)\right| $$

for all integers $\ t\ $ such that $ 2\le t\le 2^n.\ $ Thus now there are some small theorems and a number of tough open questions about $\ top(n;t).\ $ Let me formulate one (approximate answers are most welcome too):

> **QUESTION**:   What are $\ t_n\ \&\ v_n\ \,(2\le t_n\le 2^n)\ $ such that
>   $$ v_n = top(n;t_n)\ =\ \max_{t\ :\ 2\le t\le 2^n}\,\ top(n;t) $$
>   for positive integers $\ n.$

Of course $\ t_n\ $ does not have to be unique.

***About Notation***: we have $\ top(2)=4\ $ *while there are only* $\ 3\ $ *different homeomorphic classes in a* $2$-*element set.*

---

In view of the @RichardStanley's answer and of my addition below, let me ask a simpler and still a specific question from in-between:

> **QUESTION**   Compute or estimate $\ top\left(n,\,\ 2^{\lfloor\frac n2   \rfloor}\right),\ $ also $\ top(n\,\ 2^{n-1}),\ top(n\,\ 2^{n-2}\ )$ and $\ top(n\,\ 2^{n-3})\ $ for $\ n>3$.

In general, can one take an advantage of an eventual divisibility $\ k\,|\,n\ $ (or similar) when computing $\ top(n\ k)\,$?

Comment: Do you want labelled and unlabelled versions?  I think the unlabelled versions correspond to partial order types or semi lattice types or some such. Gerhard "It's Some Kind Of Structure" Paseman, 2016.10.07.

Comment: My definitions are formal, explicit, and indeed, they correspond to the unlabeled quasi-orders. I.e. the homeomorphic (or isometric) examples, which are not identical, count as different.

Comment: Oh, how I dislike those "labeled" and "unlabeled" terms! To me, they are not intuitive, just the opposite.

Comment: There is being intuitive, and then there is being communicative.  I think both are possible in this case.  I advise finding synonyms quickly so that you can preserve your intuition and make it easier to communicate it to us.  Gerhard "How About Named And Unnamed?" Paseman, 2016.10.07.

Comment: Closely related: http://mathoverflow.net/q/75933/41291

Comment: @Włodzimierz Your question describes the labelled case, not the unlabelled case. The idea is that for the labelled case the elements of $X$ are distinguishable, say $X=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and in the unlabelled case they are indistinguishable, like electrons. See http://oeis.org/A000798 for the totals. It doesn't answer your question, but one of the citations there might be useful.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay, thank you. That was indeed my instinct, that labeled meant to distinguish otherwise isomorphic cases. Somehow, some texts got me confused. I was never writing or thinking in terms of labeled/unlabeled.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე--only somewhat related, not closely at all.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński: Yes, unlabelled usually means to count isomorphism classes, which is *much* harder than the labelled case. For example, there is no known formula for the number of isomorphism classes of trees with $n$ nodes, but the number of trees with node set $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$ is simply $n^{n-2}$. I have upvoted your comment about this terminology of (un)labelled structures being not intuitive. But one can get used to it. By the way, there is no need to restrict $2 \leq t \leq 2^n$, since otherwise $top(n,t)=0$ anyway.

Comment: Clearly, $top(n,2)=top(n,2^n)=1$. What can we say about $top(n,3)$? Is it $2^n-2$?

Comment: @HeinrichD, indeed, $top(n\ 3)=2^n-2$ for $n>0$ because in addition to $\emptyset$ and the whole $n$-space you have to name exactly one and an otherwise arbitrary subset of the space.

Comment: @HeinrichD, "By the way,..." -- indeed, my point was to avoid talking about the trivial cases. (Thanks to you, I have failed miserably).

Answer (score 4):

Information on this question is given in
https://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.2550.pdf. In particular,
$t(n,k)$ was computed for $k\leq 23$ by Erné and Stege, *Ars
Combinatoria* **40** (1995), 65--88. For $k\leq 5$ we have
$t(n,3)=2^n-2$, and for $n\geq 4$,
  $$ t(n,4) = \frac 12(2\cdot 3^n-5\cdot 2^n+4) $$
  $$ t(n,5) = 4^n-3\cdot 3^n+2^n-3. $$

Comment: these examples are mentioned in Munkres' own textbook in the very first chapter -- and not further discussed in favor of subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ etc

Answer (score 0):

In view of the @RichardStanley's answer (thank you!) let me add some information from the other end, I'll assume $\ n\ge 2$:

- $\ top(n\,\ 2^n)\ =\ 1 $
- $\ top(n\,\ k)\ =\ 0\quad $ for $\ 3\cdot 2^{n-2} < k < 2^n $
- $\ top(n\ \ 3\!\cdot\!2^{n-2})\,\ =\,\  n\cdot(n-1) $

After a couple more steps in this direction, the exact calculations get very tough.

---

We also get the following general **property**:

$$ top\left(n\ t\right) > 0\quad\Rightarrow\quad
      top\left(n\!+\!m\quad 2^m\!\cdot\! top\left(n\ t\right)
\right)\ >\ 0 $$

Comment: I think you mean $\frac 34\cdot 2^n$, not $\frac 34\cdot 2^{n-2}$. For further results in this direction, see Theorems 1' and 2' of http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/3.pdf (one of my first papers).

Comment: @RichardStanley, thank you. And now, I,v fixed the typo, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The @RichardStanley's approach to the topic of this thread (see: math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/3.pdf) was via orders (partial and quasi). I'd like to give a gist of a topological approach--this was a byproduct of my replacement of filters and Moore-Smith sequences by *singular spaces*. It's a question of elegance, that's all.

The combinatorics underneath is the same but the approaches feel different--I apply results for the general spaces to the finite spaces.

**DEFINITION** A topological space (and its topology) is called singular when it has exactly one non-isolated point.

Given a topological space $\ (X\ T),\ $ and $\ a\in X,\ $ let:

$$ T_a\ :=\ 2^{X\setminus \{a\}}\,\cup\, \{G\in T: a\in G\} $$

Then $\ T_a\ $ is a singular topology such that $\ T\subseteq T_a.\ $ It follows that every maximal topology is singular, where maximal means *maximal non-discrete*. Furthermore:

**THEOREM 0**   Topologies, maximal among the singular topologies, are the same as maximal topologies.

**THEOREM 1**   Every topology $\ T\ $ is the intersection of the singular topologies (in the same set of points) that contain $\ T$.

**THEOREM 2**   Every singular topology $\ S\ $ is the intersection of the maximal singular topologies that contain $\ S.\ $ Every topology $\ T\ $ is the intersection of the maximal (singular) topologies that contain $\ T$.

In the case of a finite space $\ (X\ T),\ $ the topology admits the minimal base function $\ \beta_T: a\mapsto \beta_T(a) := \bigcap\{G\in T: a\in G\}.\ $ We get a reverse ordering of these functions w.r. to topologies:

$$ S\subseteq T\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \beta_T\le_X\beta_S $$

for arbitrary topologies $\ S\ T\ $ in $\ X,\ $ where

$$ \beta_T\le_X\beta_S\quad\Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\quad
        \forall_{x\in X}\,\ \beta_T(x)\subseteq\beta_S(x) $$

It's clear that in the finite case, a topology $\ T\ $ in $\ X\ $ is maximal $\ \Leftrightarrow $

$$ \exists_{a\ b\in X: a\ne b}\ \ \left(\left(\beta_T(a)\, =\, \{a\ b\}\right)
   \ \ \&\ \ 
  \left(\forall_{x\in X\setminus\{a\}}\ \beta_T(x)=\{x\}\right)\right) $$

Call such topology $\ T_{a\ b}.\ $ Obviously, $ |T_{a\ b}|=\frac 34\cdot 2^n,\ $ hence

- $\ \forall_{t:\ \frac 34\cdot 2^n\,<\,t\,<\,2^n}\ \ top(n\ t) = 0 $
- $\ top\left(n\ \ \frac 34\!\cdot\! 2^n\right)\ =\,\ n\cdot(n-1) $

---

Next step. Consider submaximal topologies, i.e. topologies which are maximal among non-discrete and non-maximal topologies. Obviously, each of them must be an intersection of exactly two maximal topologies (see the 2nd part of Theorem 2 above). This leads to $5$ cases (all points $a$ and $b$, and eventually $c$ or even $d$, are all different):

- $\ T := T_{a\ b}\cap T_{b\ a},\ \ |T| = 2^{n-1} $ -- **remark**: the non-$T_0$ case;
- $\ T := T_{a\ b}\cap T_{a c},\ \ |T| = 2^{n-1}+2^{n-3}\ $ -- **remark**: $\ \beta_T(a) = \{a\ b\ c\};$
- $\ T := T_{a\ c}\cap T_{b\ c},\ \ |T| = 2^{n-2}+2\cdot 2^{n-3}+2^{n-3}=2^{n-1}+2^{n-3} $
- $\ T := T_{a\ b}\cap T_{b\ c},\ \ |T| = 2^{n-2}+2^{n-3}+2^{n-3} = 2^{n-1} $ -- **remark**: $\ \beta_T(a) = \{a\ b\ c\};$
- $\ T:= T_{a\ b}\cup T_{c\ d},\ \ |T| = 2^{n-2}+2\cdot 2^{n-3}+2^{n-4} = 2^{n-1}+2^{n-4} $

Next, one may consider the subsubmaximal topologies $\ T\ $ (some of these cardinalities $\ T\ $ coincide with the previous submaximal case). Etc. etc.